# cron: run a script that sources a function

Tags: bash, cron

I have script that does a bunch of stuff. It sources a bunch of functions that are in the directory the script is being run from. i.e.

```
/home/me/script.sh
/home/me/function1
/home/me/function2
```

If I `cd` into /home/me and run `./script.sh` everything works fine. The functions are sourced and do what needs to be done.

However, if I try to run this as a cron job, it will run up until the point I am trying to source the functions, and then it just stops and the process is terminated (if I run it directly from the directory, at least I get some errors).

Like wise, if I try to run this from another directory, I get a bunch of errors. e.g.

```
cd /opt/
/home/me/script.sh

function1: command not found
function2: command not found
```

I'm sure this has something to do with environmental variables, but I have no idea which ones. I have tried setting (in crontab):

```
PATH=/home/me
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

But that doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated. I don't want to hard code in the paths to the functions, and instead make them relative to the path the script is in (preferably the same dir).

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: show us the script.sh function1 function2 content, and how you write your crontab

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably aware of this, but just to be clear: A **shell function** does not have a path. They just need to be loaded into the current shell by sourcing the script that contains them:

```
source /path/to/functions
```

or

```
cd /path/to/functions
source functions
```

If you are talking about **shell programs** (scripts) instead, then you need to account for the fact that on Unix-like OS, the current directory is never in the `PATH` by default:

```
/path/to/functions/function1
```

or

```
cd /path/to/functions
./function1
```

You tagged your question `Bash`, but note that to be POSIX-**compatible** (e.g. if using `sh`), you have to use the `.` keyword (instead of either `.` or `source` on Bash) and the same restrictions regarding the `PATH` as for command execution apply, see [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

```
. ./function1
```